# How can I make these 2 functions to be void() only?

Tags: c#, mysql, adapter, bindingsource

I have a code that will load Data to a grid view and let the user to edit and update the table.

In order to do that I'm "forcing" myself to pass around an Adapter instance.

How can I avoid this so the 2 functions will be void only ?

```
public static MySqlDataAdapter LoadMySQLData(DataGridView dgv, string RequestTableQuery)
    {
        MySqlConnection privateConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(RequestTableQuery, privateConnection);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource { DataSource = dt };
        dgv.DataSource = bs;
        return adapter;
    }

    public static void SaveMySQLData(DataGridView dgv, MySqlDataAdapter adapter)
    {
        BindingSource bs = dgv.DataSource as BindingSource;
        bs.EndEdit();
        adapter.Update(bs.DataSource as DataTable);
    }
```

Comment: The Adapter can be created in each method (also, highly recommend `using` and closing the connection after the usages..). At some point there has to be "something" that knows how to align a particular Load + Save.

Comment: @user2864740 "closing the connection" - there is no connection here, nor does there need to be with a DataAdapter; it knows how to open and close the connection itself so no need to mess with it unless you're manually enrolling it in a transaction

Comment: Thanks guys but that isn't the issue. Creating multiple adapters on multiple forms is the same as passing around the adapter as it is with the above code, not what I want at all...

Comment: *"not what I want at all"*  Then it's not exactly clear what you want. To make the method return `void`, change the return type to `void` and remove the `return` statement (and make `adapter` a class field so other methods can access it). But it's probably not a good idea to use a common adapter like that. To avoid using/passing a common instance, each method should create and dispose of it's own instance (they're cheap).

Comment: Basically I'm looking for way to do the same 2 operations (not necessarily using the same code nor the same logic )  without passing an Adapter . I was thinking about using a global variable but couldn't figure a way to implement the idea because I will have multiple grid views so I will  have to pass some indication on which one was I refraining to when I clicked save.